# How can I parse multiple filenames from xml file using regex_substr

Tags: regex, substr, db2-400

I have a FTP log in an XML format stored in CLOB column and I need to get the filenames it found and retrieved. Using Table/Lateral along with REGEX_SUBSTR I can get the what I need for a KNOWN amount files, but I can't figure out to handle an unknown amount of files. There is a field that returns the number of files found  `<FilesProcessed>3</FilesProcessed>`. Is there a way to use that field to help parse the filenames? or , more important, is there simply a better way to do this?

(I'm using a CTE here, but I will pulling this from a DB table (with an obscene amount of columns, but no filenames!).

```
With PAYLOAD_DATA(LOGS) as(
VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InboundMFTEventDetailsDocument>
  <MFTEventExecutionDetails>
    <Status>Successful</Status>
    <FilesProcessed>3</FilesProcessed>
    <MFTEventLogID>5dn39m00fgmdefo80002g7ki</MFTEventLogID>
    <ExecutionLogs>
      <Logs>Finding file(s) in VFS Path:/Wholesale/CS/Inbound/SFTP/PROD-OUT-Shipment/, URL:SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/. 
        Filename Filter = INVPTH*.txt
        Found following 3 file(s).
           SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320006396.txt
           SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320009986.txt
           SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH092720210320009986.txt
      </Logs>
      <Logs>Starting copy of file(s) from VFS Path:/Wholesale/CS/Inbound/SFTP/PROD-OUT-Shipment/, URL:SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320006396.txt to VFS Path:/Wholesale/RLM/Outbound/SFTP/SERVERSERVICES-INBOUND-SHIPH/, URL:SFTP://MKWHLDV.kors.local:22/SERVERSERVICES/INBOUND/SHIPH/INVPTH033020210320006396.txt
Copy finished:VFS Path:/Wholesale/CS/Inbound/SFTP/PROD-OUT-Shipment/, URL:SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320006396.txt
</Logs>
      <Logs>...</Logs>
      <Logs>...</Logs>
      <Logs>...</Logs>
    </ExecutionLogs>
  </MFTEventExecutionDetails>
</InboundMFTEventDetailsDocument>'))

SELECT  FILENAME
FROM PAYLOAD_DATA A,
TABLE (VALUES (REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]') - 0)),
              (REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]') - 1)),
              (REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]') - 2)),
              (REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]') - 3)))  as G(FILENAME)
```

```
SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH092720210320009986.txt 
SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320009986.txt 
SFTP://ftp.some_server.com:22/UAT/OUT/Shipment/INVPTH033020210320006396.txt
```

Comment: Please add the tag of database your are using to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
With PAYLOAD_DATA(LOGS) as(
...
)
occurrences (occ) as (values 1 union all select occ + 1 from occurrences where occ < (SELECT  REGEXP_COUNT(LOGS, '  SFTP://.*[\r\n][   |\<]') FROM PAYLOAD_DATA))
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOGS, '  (SFTP://.*)[\r\n][   |\<]', 1, occ, '', 1) filename from PAYLOAD_DATA, occurrences
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Just what I needed.